# D3 chart giving error Cannot read property 'length' of undefined in zoom

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I am using d3.v4 charts. while zooming I am getting an error Cannot read property 'length' of undefined at line 'grp.select(".area").attr("d", area.x(function(d) {return xt(d);}));'. On browser console it is showing as

```
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at SVGPathElement.t (d3.v4.min.js:2)
    at SVGPathElement.<anonymous> (d3.v4.min.js:2)
    at pt.each (d3.v4.min.js:2)
    at pt.attr (d3.v4.min.js:2)
    at SVGSVGElement.zoomed (pen.js:69)
    at p.apply (d3.v4.min.js:2)
    at N (d3.v4.min.js:2)
    at c.emit (d3.v4.min.js:2)
    at c.zoom (d3.v4.min.js:2)
    at d3.v4.min.js:2**
```

please help me with this error. 
Refer following link for codepen example https://codepen.io/rohitbagde/pen/ZXEVRp

```
var dataArray=[11,14,27,30,43,47,60,69,77,100];
var dataMonths=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
var dataDate=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

var height=150;
var width=1000;
var parseMonth= d3.timeParse('%m');
var area = d3.area().x(function(d,i){return x(parseMonth(dataMonths[i]));} )
            .y0(height)
            .y1(function(d){return y(d);});


var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("height","100%").attr("width","100%");

var grp=svg.append('g').attr('transform','translate(40,0)').attr("class", "charts");

// Domain is referred to data i.e. x-axis
//This for y scale
var y=d3.scaleLinear().domain([0,200]).range([150,0]);
var x=d3.scaleTime()
.domain([d3.min(dataMonths,function(d){ return parseMonth(d);}),
        d3.max(dataMonths,function(d){ return parseMonth(d);})])
.range([0,1000]);

//This is for yaxis
var yAxis=d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(5).tickPadding(10);
var xAxis=d3.axisBottom(x);

grp.append('g').attr('class','axis y').call(yAxis);
grp.append('g').attr('class','axis x').attr('transform','translate(0,150)').call(xAxis);

//for plotting lines
grp.append("path")
  .attr("fill","none")
.attr("stroke","black")
.attr("stroke-width","2")
.attr("class", "area")
  .attr("d",area(dataArray));

//For plotting points
grp.selectAll("circle.grpcircle")
.data(dataArray)
.enter().append("circle")
.attr("class","circle")
.attr("cx",function(d,i){return x(parseMonth(dataMonths[i]));})
.attr("cy",function(d){return y(d);})
.attr("r",'4') 



 //For zooming
var zoom = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, 32])
    .translateExtent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
    .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

var d0=parseMonth(1);
var d1=parseMonth(12);
 svg.call(zoom).transition()
      .duration(1500)
      .call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity
          .scale(width / (x(d1) - x(d0)))
          .translate(-x(d0), 0)); 

function zoomed() {
  var t = d3.event.transform, xt = t.rescaleX(x);
  area.x(function(d) {alert("Hi");return xt(d);});

  grp.select(".area").attr("d", area.x(function(d) {return xt(d);}));
  grp.select(".x").call(xAxis.scale(xt));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to bind the data array to the SVG path initially to make it work.

```
//for plotting lines
grp.append("path")
  .datum(dataArray)
  .attr("fill","none")
  .attr("stroke","black")
  .attr("stroke-width","2")
  .attr("class", "area")
  .attr("d",area);
```

```js
var dataArray = [11, 14, 27, 30, 43, 47, 60, 69, 77, 100];
var dataMonths = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
var dataDate = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

var height = 150;
var width = 1000;
var parseMonth = d3.timeParse('%m');
var area = d3.area().x(function(d, i) {
    return x(parseMonth(dataMonths[i]));
  })
  .y0(height)
  .y1(function(d) {
    return y(d);
  });


var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("height", "100%").attr("width", "100%");


svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")
  .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

var grp = svg.append('g').attr('transform', 'translate(40,0)').attr("class", "charts");

// Domain is referred to data i.e. x-axis
//This for y scale
var y = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 200]).range([150, 0]);
var x = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain([d3.min(dataMonths, function(d) {
      return parseMonth(d);
    }),
    d3.max(dataMonths, function(d) {
      return parseMonth(d);
    })
  ])
  .range([0, 1000]);

//This is for yaxis
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(5).tickPadding(10);
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x);

grp.append('g').attr('class', 'axis y').call(yAxis);
grp.append('g').attr('class', 'axis x').attr('transform', 'translate(0,150)').call(xAxis);

//for plotting lines
grp.append("path")
  .datum(dataArray)
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("stroke", "black")
  .attr("stroke-width", "2")
  .attr("class", "area1")
  .attr("d", area);

grp.selectAll("circle.grpcircle")
  .data(dataArray)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("class", "circle")
  .attr("cx", function(d, i) {
    return x(parseMonth(dataMonths[i]));
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return y(d);
  })
  .attr("r", '4')

//For zooming
var zoom = d3.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([1, 32])
  .translateExtent([
    [0, 0],
    [width, height]
  ])
  .extent([
    [0, 0],
    [width, height]
  ])
  .on("zoom", zoomed);

var d0 = parseMonth(1);
var d1 = parseMonth(12);
svg.call(zoom).transition()
  .duration(1500)
  .call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity
    .scale(width / (x(d1) - x(d0)))
    .translate(-x(d0), 0));

function zoomed() {
  var t = d3.event.transform,
    xt = t.rescaleX(x);
  grp.select(".area1").attr("d", area.x(function(d, i) {
    return xt(parseMonth(dataMonths[i]));
  }));
  grp.select(".x").call(xAxis.scale(xt));
  grp.selectAll("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d, i) {
      return xt(parseMonth(dataMonths[i]));
    });
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.area1 {
  clip-path: url(#clip);
}
```

```html
<body>

  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Tried this solution. But it is showing same error and now all the points and path are not visible.

Comment: Thank you. This solution worked for me. One another thing that I want to do is to zoom also the points which are shown there in my code snippet with class 'circle'. How to do that? Right now points are not getting zoomed. Only path is getting zoomed.  Please help. I am new to D3 charts.

Comment: Found the solution. have to use  grp.selectAll("circle").attr("cx", function(d,i){return xt(parseMonth(dataMonths[i]));});
  Thank you.

Comment: I was little busy. Glad you got it resolved by yourselves.